# Entering values in database in unicode

Tags: php, mysql

I want to save data in  Hindi Unicode format in my database using PHP. I have added few lines of codes to my database connection page.

```
mysql_query('SET character_set_results=utf8');
mysql_query('SET names=utf8');
mysql_query('SET character_set_client=utf8');
mysql_query('SET character_set_connection=utf8');
mysql_query('SET character_set_results=utf8');
mysql_query('SET collation_connection=utf8_general_ci');
```

Also have added this line to page where I am inputing and showing my Unicode data to its `head` attribute

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
```

But my data is storing in database as '?????' and also displaying in same format. Even my new line character is also skipped thats data is showing in single line.

Comment: How do you view that data? phpmyadmin?

Comment: What character set are your database tables in?

Comment: how are you inserting the data? The PHP strings likely aren't Unicode.

Comment: I am adding in simple way using '$_POST' and putting values in variable.

Comment: Got solution but my new character is skipping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that your database is using different character set. Make sure you use create your database with:

```
create database something         -- or 'alter database something' in case it exists
default character set utf8
default collate utf8_general_ci
```

At the moment you are just telling your query to be encoded in UTF-8, however your database is probably still using different character set.

Also make sure you actually output these data properly, encoded in UTF-8 too.

Comment: I have already created database Now instead of editing each column. How can I make changes to whole db at once.

Comment: Ondrej Slinták is correct. set your table collate to the utf8_general_ci in mysql

Comment: select the table in phpmyadmin go to operation and change the collate

Comment: or use `alter database_name etc etc`

Comment: @Ondrej Slinták : Edited & now my problem is solved. Though data is displaying in correct form but still yet newline character, tabs character, paragraph character are skipping..

Comment: PHP won't change, for example, new lines to <br> automatically. You have to change them before outputting to HTML.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the encoding of your database using [mysql_client_encoding](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-client-encoding.php), from that page:

```
$link    = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
$charset = mysql_client_encoding($link);
echo "The current character set is: $charset";
```

The encoding is probably not utf8 but you can change that using mysql from the command line or a tool like phpMyAdmin.

Also note that according to the php manual, [mysql_set_charset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php) is preferred over using a query to set the character set.

Comment: <code>The current character set is: Resource id #2</code> Displaying this message.

Comment: @Aditii Did you modify the first line with your login information?

Comment: Sorry, which line you are talking about?

Comment: @Aditii Ummmmmmmm, the first?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK `SET names=utf8` is not correct, it should be `SET NAMES 'utf8'`

Comment: Edited & now my problem is solved. Though data is displaying in correct form but still yet newline character, tabs character, paragraph character are skipping.

Comment: You mean, they are not inserted into the database?

Answer (score 0):

the more frequent cause of this is the Header content-type.

If apache sends an header content-type it has a priority than the meta html.

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```